# How to insert data by using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets (sheet1,sheet2,sheet3) in sheet1 has all user ID, sheet2 has logon user ID and sheet3 is empty. The point is... I need to put not logon user ID into sheet3 but my code fail. If it's a stupid question that because I'm newbie with VBA

Here my code:

```
Sub NotLog()

Dim c1 As Range

Dim c2 As Range

Dim c3 As Range

Dim sh1 As Worksheet

Dim sh2 As Worksheet

Dim sh3 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALl USer")
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("8_Logon_SOE_by_group")
    Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Not Logon")

    For Each c1 In sh1.Range("A2:A99")
        For Each c2 In sh2.Range("A3:A99")
            If c1 <> c2 Then
                For Each c3 In sh3.Range("A2:A99")
                    If IsEmpty(Range("c3").Value) = True Then
                        c3 = c1
                    ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("c3").Value) = False Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next c3
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c2
    Next c1

End Sub
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kDEH.png ......It's my output.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWSZM.png ......It should be like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. It has been modified slightly by first removing the contents of Not Logon and then filling one user per row that has not logged in. A counter has been added to increment the next cell to fill if a user has not logged on. A boolean variable has been added to track whether that user has or has not logged on.

```
Sub NotLog()

    Dim c1 As Range
    Dim c2 As Range
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim sh3 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALl USer")
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("8_Logon_SOE_by_group")
    Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Not Logon")

    ' empty our not logon sheet
    sh3.Cells.Clear

    ' used to print into sheet 2 line by line a list of
    ' users that have not logged in
    Dim CellCounter As Integer
    Dim TempFound As Boolean
    CellCounter = 1

    For Each c1 In sh1.Range("A2:A99")
        TempFound = False

        ' match user with login
        For Each c2 In sh2.Range("A3:A99")
            If c1.Value = c2.Value Then
                TempFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c2

        ' if user has not logged in, list the user
        ' in Not Logon sheet
        If Not TempFound Then
            sh3.Cells(CellCounter, 1).Value = c1.Value
            CellCounter = CellCounter + 1
        End If

    Next c1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I follow what you are doing, is it like the opposite of a vlookup where if its in list a but not list b then put it in list c?

If that is the issues then the problem is that you need

```
For Each c2 In sh2.Range("A3:A99")
    If c1 <> c2 Then
```

to complete for all rows before you decide if it is a match, and then write it out to the third sheet.

So if I understood you properly something like this would work:

```
Sub NotLog()
   Dim c1 As Range
   Dim c2 As Range
   Dim c3 As Range
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet
   Dim sh2 As Worksheet
   Dim isMatch As Boolean

   Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALl USer")
   Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("8_Logon_SOE_by_group")
   Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Not Logon")

   For Each c1 In sh1.Range("A2:A99")
      isMatch = False
      For Each c2 In sh2.Range("A2:A99")
         If c1 = c2 Then
            isMatch = True
            Exit For
         End If
      Next c2
      If Not isMatch Then ' check once you have checked all on second sheet
         'This is quicker than looping to find the bottom blank row
         'It basically says go to bottom row, then ctrl+Up then down one
         sh3.Range("a" & sh3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = c1
      End If
   Next c1
End Sub
```

Good luck